# Stream API получить сумму всех ключей Map

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Почему-то не получается посчитать сумму всех ключей

```
 Man vasia = new Man("vasia", "Pupkin", 2, 24, odessa);
 Man olaf = new Man("olaf", "olaf", 2, 24, moskov);
...
```

надо посчитать сумму всех детей у пользователей
Я написал так, но x.get(x) нет возможности выбрать,не пойму почему.

```
 final Map<Integer, List<Man>> coll = manLinkedList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Man::getCountOfChildren));

        int sum = coll.keySet().stream().mapToInt(x -> почему тут не могу испольховать x.get(x) + x ).sum();

        System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: LinkedList<Man> manLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        manLinkedList.add(vasia);
создание листа

Comment: чтобы использовать sum вам надо стрим преобразовать в интовый стрим, для этого вместо map вызывайте mapToInt. но все равно непонятно , почему у вас ключ в мэпе - количество детей? я так понимаю, что для того, чтобы считать количество детей, надо чтобы количество было значением, а ключ определял, у кого мы это считаем

Comment: За mapToInt спасибо, я просмотрел.
если я правильно составил первый запрос, то в coll должно попасть первым значением количество детей, а вторым Лист с людьми.
Далее я думал просто сумировать все ключи и выдать рузультат.

Comment: подождите, вам надо просто количество вообще всех детей или количество детей для каждого пользователя?

Comment: количество всех детей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужен Map, все на много проще:

```
int sum = manLinkedList.stream().mapToInt(Man::getCountOfChildren).sum();
```

И еще... Если у вас нет весомых аргументов для использования LinkedList откажитесь от него в пользу ArrayList. Не забывайте, что LinkedList является двусвязным списком, соответственно, каждый его элемент - полноценная нода со всеми вытекающими. Посему при использовании ArrayList вы в подавляющем большинстве случаев выиграете.

Comment: спасибо, LinkedList надо использовать, так написанно в задании.